# How to check if the default configuration has been loaded in CI3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working in a custom library for a project to be used in CI3.1 (CodeIgniter 3.1). This is a piece of code:

```
class NavigationMenu
{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct($params = ['config' => 'navigation'])
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->helper('url');  
        $this->CI->config->load($params['config'], true);
        $this->CI->load->model('nav_model', 'nav');
    }
    ....
}
```

The default config 'navigation.php` file have the following code:

```
$config['navigation_open']          = '<ul class="nav">';
$config['navigation_close']         = '</ul>';
$config['item_open']                = '<li>';
$config['item_open_active_class']   = 'active';
```

As you can see I am loading the `url` helper, the `navigation` config file and the `nav_model` model. Is there any way to check if them has been loaded previously? Could be the case when I want to save time and then setup the `autoload.php` as follow:

```
$autoload['helper'] = ['url'];
$autoload['config'] = ['navigation'];
$autoload['model']  = ['nav_model'];
```

If that's the case how do I check if has been loaded in order to not try to load once again?

I have look over the documentation for [config class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) and couldn't find anything helpful

Comment: You can check if item is set. `if ( ! isset( $this->config->item('item_open_active_class') ) { $this->config->load('navigation'); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check is any function from `url` helper available at the moment, so You'll be able to understand was helper loaded or You should do it by Yourself:

```
if(!function_exists('site_url'))
    $this->CI->load->helper('url');
```

It's an easy trick if You need to check is any helper was loaded, but it's not too clear how to check is config/model loaded, so if You really want to create Your own autoloader, You need to do similar checks with the core object (`$this->CI`):

```
if(!method_exists($this->CI,'nav'))
     $this->CI->load->model('nav_model', 'nav');
```